# What is this issue with win32com excel module with python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to populate excel using win32com module in python

```
sheet.Range("A1", "A24").value = somelist #i.e. [] of len 24
```

This should actually put like this

```
A1 = somelist[0]
A2 = somelist[1]
   .
   .
   .
A24 = somelist[23]
```

But instead it just puts `somelist[0]` in all the cells A1 to A24.

```
wsrange = wsoutput.Range(column+"2", column+str(range_val+1)) #(A2, A24)
wsrange.Value = loan.values()
```

Can you tell me what is going on here?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `loan.values()` is, don't you think?

Comment: its a list, sry bout that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `somelist` is a row of 24 value, e.g:

```
somelist = [1, 2, 3, ..]
```

This will work if you are setting rows, e.g. `sheet.Range('A1', 'Z1').Value = somelist`.

You want to set columns, you need to flip it so it becomes:

```
lsomelist = [[1], [2], [3], ..]
```

you can use `zip` like (`V` is capital in `Value`):

```
sheet.Range('A1', 'A24').Value = tuple(zip(somelist))
```